# Add more than one SearchBar in tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

It's possible to add two searchBar's in one View controller. For example, I have a static table view with two rows, in each row I want to have `UITableViewCell` with searchBar. I can't find any way how can I do this in the Net. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **YES**. You can place as many `UISearchBar`s as you want. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` and place a `UISearchBar` inside of it.